# How can I stop my program from quitting after second loop?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Excersises
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input;
        bool correct = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Please choose your favorite beverage");
        Console.WriteLine("For Cola type '1'");
        Console.WriteLine("For Sprite type '2'");
        Console.WriteLine("For Fanta, type '3'");
        Console.WriteLine("For Bitter Lemon, type '4'");
        Console.WriteLine("For Beer, type '5'");

        input = Console.ReadLine();

        while (correct)
        {

            if (input == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enjoy your Cola!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                correct = true;

            }
            else if (input == "2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enjoy your Sprite!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                correct = true;

            }
            else if (input == "3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enjoy your Fanta!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                correct = true;

            }
            else if (input == "4")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enjoy your Bitter Lemon!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                correct = true;

            }
            else if (input == "5")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enjoy your beer!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                correct = true;
            }
            else if (input == " ")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid input!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                correct = false;

            }
        }

    }




   }
```

I've got literally no idea why my program quits after I try to input for the second time. If I input " ", it functions as it is supposed to and prints 'That is not a valid input'. However, I'm unable to input after that. I've tried the while loop to prevent it from closing, but without success. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `static void main()` and step into (default is F11 in VS) your program and watch the control flow with various inputs.

Comment: This is a good use case for a `switch` statement, instead of chained `if`s. Also, you are only checking a single space character for invalid input; what if the user entered _two_ spaces, or even something entirely different like "hello"?

Answer (score 2):

You did nothing wrong. But you are setting `correct = false;` and your program only carries on `while(correct)`. After an invalid input, it stops iterating, finds nothing else to do, and finishes correctly. You might want to change the condition on the loop to some exit condition, say `while(continue)` and then have a specific input where `continue = false`.

Edit: Example

```
bool workToDo = true;
while(workToDo) {
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose your favorite beverage (and other text)");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (input == "1") {
        Console.WriteLine("Enjoy your Cola!");
    }
    // Your normal options go here and for the other inputs.
    else if(input == "exit") {
        workToDo = false;
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid input! Try again!");
    }
```

Note that I'm not using the `correct` variable. I don't know if you need to check for correct options for some other purpose.

Comment: Ah! Glad to hear that. Could you please give a brief example of that continue loop? When i try to replace 'correct' with 'continue' it doesn't really seem to do much. Must admit i've never heard of 'continue' as a function before.

Comment: @Kairo He meant for you to replace `correct` with a completely new _variable_ `continue`. However, I would NOT use that name since `continue` is a keyword; specifically, it jumps to the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

What is the exit condition? Based on your comments, it sounds like your intended response to an invalid input is to display an error message and then continue asking for input. If you don't want your loop to exit, just change while(correct) to while(true), in which case you'll keep looping forever.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic surrounding your `correct` flag is wrong. You should start with `bool correct = true;` and flip the logic in the while to `while (!correct)`.

You could try this approach instead:

```
string[] beverages = new string[]
{
    "Cola", "Sprite", "Fanta", "Bitter Lemon", "Beer"
};

Console.WriteLine("Please choose your favorite beverage");
for (int i = 0; i < beverages.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("For {0} type '{1}'", beverages[i], i + 1);
}

bool correct = false;
while (!correct)
{
    int input = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
    {
        correct = Enumerable.Range(1, beverages.Length).Contains(input);
    }
    if (correct)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enjoy your {0}!", beverages[input - 1]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid input!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer the best, except for the line with `Enumerable.Range`. Why not just do `correct = input > 0 && input <= beverages.Length;`? (Instead of making a new `IEnumerable` object and iterating over it to see if it contains `input`...)

Comment: @Ignaus - To be honest I originally wrote the line like you suggested, but then I went with the enumerable approach simply for readability. I didn't bother with the performance issue because it's only 5 elements.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your while should be

```
while(!correct)
```

rather than

```
while(correct)
```

Just try to read it in English: while request is not correct keep asking what they want
and you wrote: while they give me a correct answer I will ask them the same question :)